# Traffic is not being spread evenly between replicas of OpenFaas functions

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, kubernetes, eks

As per this [documentation](https://docs.openfaas.com/deployment/troubleshooting/#traffic-is-not-being-spread-evenly-between-functions), I have configured `direct_functions` to false, which allows the provider to balance traffic between replicas of OpenFaas functions. But it sends the traffic to only one replica. Without using any service mesh solution how do I archive the fairly balance the traffic to all pods that are related to one openfaas function? I have deployed OpenFaas on the EKS cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have set the service type as loadbalancer.
Additionally please check the following link.

https://github.com/openfaas/faas-netes/tree/master/chart/openfaas#endpoint-load-balancing

Comment: As per the above link, Disabling the KeepAlive connection cant be done because there is a requirement to have a KeepAlive connection. At last, I have configured the Linkerd as a solution for this. Thank you for your suggestion.